# Index alignments

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment

If you compile the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
    \label{dipole}
    \langle AJ_{K_{a}K_{c}}\vert \mu \vert A{J'}_{K'_{a}K'_{c}}\rangle \neq 0   
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

You'll notice that the subscript indexes *K* are not aligned properly. Any suggestion to overcome this or is the placement indeed correct?

I did try to implement a `\vphantom{'}` to see if changing the vertical alignment would correct the issue, but to no avail

Comment: What do you mean with *not properly aligned*? I can see no problem when I compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert a dummy superscript.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \label{dipole}
    \langle AJ_{K^{}_{a}K^{}_{c}}\vert \mu \vert A{J'}_{K'_{a}K'_{c}}\rangle \neq 0
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ugh! The simplest solutions are many times the hardest to find indeed - I completely neglected that!